# yarn install failing due to http://blip.strongloop.com/ being offline

Tags: yarnpkg

yarn install

or

yarn upgrade

result in this error:

```
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "http://blip.strongloop.com/zone@0.3.4: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND blip.strongloop.com".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/ff/projects/network_tools_portal/network_tools_portal_ui/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade for documentation about this command.
```

the error log includes this additional info:

```
  zone.js@~0.10.3:
    version "0.10.3"
    resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.10.3.tgz"
    integrity sha512-LXVLVEq0NNOqK/fLJo3d0kfzd4sxwn2/h67/02pjCjfKDxgx1i9QqpvtHD8CrBnSSwMw5+dy11O7FRX5mkO7Cg==
  
  zone.js@~0.11.4:
    version "0.11.5"
    resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js/-/zone.js-0.11.5.tgz"
    integrity sha512-D1/7VxEuQ7xk6z/kAROe4SUbd9CzxY4zOwVGnGHerd/SgLIVU5f4esDzQUsOCeArn933BZfWMKydH7l7dPEp0g==
    dependencies:
      tslib "^2.3.0"
  
  zone@^0.3.4:
    version "0.3.4"
    resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/zone/-/zone-0.3.4.tgz"
    integrity sha1-XshPKNHiYftrLpoDHMrOZOnH3ec=
    optionalDependencies:
      sl-blip "http://blip.strongloop.com/zone@0.3.4"
```

Seems like the optional dependency, sl-blip, is the problem.  It seems to not be on the interwebs anymore.   Any help would be greatly appreciated

BTW, there is no proxy at play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I removed Yarn from the equation and did an npm update and the problem was gone.